# How to convert Generic Views to Class based Views for lists with modals

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to convert generic views to class based views, so that I can get some better readability in my code.

From this I want to be able to create a function so that I can show modals for individual items in a list. I'm new to django so I don't know what I can try, I've searched online and read the docs but not having any luck.

View I'm currently using:

```
    def my_booking_list(request):
        booking_lab = Reservation.objects.filter(username=request.user.username).order_by('-id')
        key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
        print(booking_lab)
        return render(request, 'my_booking_list.html', {'booking_labs': booking_lab, 'key': key})
```

Class based view I have no idea what I'm doing with (am I at least on the right track?):

```
    class MyBookingsView(ListView):
        def get(self,request ,pk):
            booking_lab = Reservation.objects.filter(username=request.user.username).order_by('-id')
            key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
            print(booking_lab)
            return render(request, 'my_booking_list.html', {'booking_labs': booking_lab, 'key': key})
```

Template (partial):

```
                                        {% if booking_labs %}
                                        {% for lab in booking_labs %}
                                        <div class="tg-dashboardservices">
                                            <div class="tg-dashboardservice">
                                                <div class="tg-servicetitle">
                                                    <h2><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".tg-categoryModal">{{lab.lab.name}}</a>
                                                        {% if lab.status == 'Accepted' %}
                                                        <span>({{lab.status}})</span>
                                                        {% elif lab.status == 'Requested' %}
                                                        <span>({{lab.status}})</span>
                                                        {% elif lab.status == 'Denied' %}
                                                        <span>({{lab.status}})</span>
                                                        {% endif %}</h2>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tg-btntimeedit">
                                                    <span>{{lab.price}}</span>
                                                    <button class="tg-btnedite"><a data-toggle="modal"
                                                                                   data-target=".tg-categoryModal">
                                                        <i class="lnr lnr-pencil"></i></a>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button class="tg-btndel"><a><i class="lnr lnr-trash"></i></a>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {%for lab in booking_labs%}
    <!--************************************
            Theme Modal Box Start
    *************************************-->
    <div class="modal fade tg-invoicemodal tg-categoryModal" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog tg-modaldialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content tg-modalcontent">
                <div class="tg-modalhead">
                    <h2>Details</h2>
                    <ul class="tg-btnaction">
                        <li class="tg-delete"><a href="#"><i class="lnr lnr-trash"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="tg-modalbody">
                    <ul class="tg-invoicedetail">
                        <li><span>Lab Booked:</span><span>{{lab.lab.name}}</span></li>
                        <li><span>Company Name:</span><span>{{lab.lab.company}}</span></li>
                        <li><span>Amount:</span><span>${{lab.lab.price}}.00</span></li>
                        <li><span>Payment Method:</span><span>Stripe</span></li>
                        <li><span>Booking Status:</span>
                            {% if lab.status == 'Accepted' %}
                            <span>{{lab.status}}</span>
                            {% elif lab.status == 'Requested' %}
                            <span>{{lab.status}}</span>
                            {% elif lab.status == 'Denied' %}
                            <span>{{lab.status}}</span>
                            {% endif %}
                        </li>
                        <li><span>Booking Dates:</span>
                            <span>From:&nbsp;{{lab.CheckInDate}} {{lab.CheckInTime}} </br>
                                To:&nbsp;{{lab.CheckOutDate}} {{lab.CheckOutTime}}</span>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>Name:</span><span>{{lab.lab.contact_person}}</span></li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Address:</span><span>{{lab.lab.street_address}}, {{lab.lab.city}}, {{lab.lab.country}}</span>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>Message:</span><span>{{lab.message}}</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <!--************************************
                Theme Modal Box End
    *************************************-->
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

The code currently displays the modal 4 times, overlapping one another, I can click off of the modal  to clear them, I know this is because of the for loop before the modal. I'm trying to achieve clicking on one item in a list to display its modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

In the list view just specify the model and paginate by count.
If you want to manually filter the queryset override the get_queryset() fun.
By default the context object name for the queryset will be **object_list** for a list view, So in the template loop over **object_list**. if you want to change it specify the context_object_name variable.

Comment: I need to change the generic view to a class based view first. I do t know how to do this.